# Why my Monorepo eslint-config-custom's dependencies doesn't installed together?

Tags: monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-berry

I have created Monorepo
The problem is that share eslint

I think package dependencies can be linked together
But, my package doesn it!

At root .eslintrc.js, it extends '@packages/eslint-config-custom' but output msg say that:
[image]

How can i fix it?
[My-repo](https://github.com/coo-kiee/Mono-Lab/tree/develop)